# Not getting expected results with RLIKE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using the next query:

```
SELECT id,module,pk,label,value
FROM traducciones
WHERE module='paginas' AND label='slug' AND value RLIKE '(tests)(-\d+)?'
```

The expected result will be only select:

- tests
- tests-1
- tests-2
- tests-N

The problem is that I'm getting:

- tests
- tests-french
- tests-u
- tests-french-u

If I try the expression on in RegExr I see that only matchs with tests, tests-1, tests-2: http://regexr.com?2su4f

How I can get only the results in the first list?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
rlike '(tests)(-[0-9]+)?$'
```